# Transfer Learning for Multivariate Regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning

As I understand it, transfer learning is termed as using the parameters of a pre-trained model, which was initially trained on a particular 'source' task, and have it train on another related 'target' task. This is useful when you don't have enough data about your target task to train a model from scratch. In image classification this involves taking a pre-trained model and only training the final classification layer on the little data you have of the target task.

My question is whether this approach (training only part of the network on the target task) is applicable to ordinary feed forward neural networks for regression tasks. If this is not applicable, how can transfer learning be performed for regression tasks?